# Can I upgrade Android on my Xoom?

Tags: motorola-droid, motorola-xoom

I have a old school 32 gig wifi-only Xoom. I would like to upgrade to a newer version of Android, so I can use Chrome.

Also I got the tablet, so I could download and manage my google home devices. Is this possible without trashing the tablet?

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of Android I can find is CyanogenMod 11. Needless to say it is not getting any updates any time soon, as CyanogenMod is dead and was superseded by LineageOS. There's some guy on the XDA forums trying to build Oreo for it but let's be real for a moment; A Tegra 2 device with 1GB RAM will run Oreo like a 486 old-school PC runs Windows 10.